# How to check if an object is nil in Swift？

Tags: ios, swift

```
var buttonSpringAnimation = self.pop_animationForKey(animationKey) as POPSpringAnimation
if buttonSpringAnimation == nil {
   buttonSpringAnimation = POPSpringAnimation(propertyNamed: kPOPLayerScaleXY)
   buttonSpringAnimation.fromValue = fromValue
   buttonSpringAnimation.toValue = toValue
   buttonSpringAnimation.springSpeed = 20.0
   buttonSpringAnimation.springBounciness = 25.0
   self.layer.pop_addAnimation(buttonSpringAnimation, forKey: animationKey)
}
```

> if buttonSpringAnimation == nil {
>   This one will complain:Cannot invoke '==' with an argument list of type '(@lvalue POPSpringAnimation, NilLiteralConvertible)'

How should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an object is of a non-optional type, it cannot be `nil`, so the compiler does not let you perform a check at all.

When you use `as` operator with no question mark, you tell swift that he conversion must succeed, in which case you will never see `nil` as the result. If you are not sure if the conversion is going to succeed or not, use conversion to an optional type. You can combine it with an implicit `nil` check like this:

```
if let buttonSpringAnimation = self.pop_animationForKey(animationKey) as? POPSpringAnimation {
    ... // This block of code will be entered only when the conversion is successful
}
```